# Map derived classes with Mapster

Tags: c#, inheritance, mapping, derived-class, mapster

e.g. I have the following class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public List<BaseClass> MyProperty  { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass {}
public class ClassA: BaseClass {}
public class ClassB: BaseClass {}
```

If I run the following code:

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.MyProperty.Add(new ClassA());
testClass.MyProperty.Add(new ClassB());

var mappedClass = testClass.Adapt<TestClass,TestClass>();
```

the new mappedClass instance has only two items of type `BaseClass` in "MyProperty" instead of new instances of `ClassA` and `ClassB`. How do I configure Mapster to don't map `ClassA` and `ClassB` to BaseClass ?

Comment: I think you meant `testClass.MyProperty.Add`

Comment: @juharr oh, thanks! :D